# Was Yadu right in denying/defying his father's (Yayati) request?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, bhagavata-purana, parents

[Srimad Bhagavatam: Canto 9, Chapter 18](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/18/):

> Text 35: King Yayāti, who was very lusty, followed his wife, caught
>   her and tried to appease her by speaking pleasing words and massaging
>   her feet, but he could not satisfy her by any means.
>
> Text 36: Śukrācārya was extremely angry. “You untruthful fool, lusting
>   after women! You have done a great wrong,” he said. “I therefore curse
>   you to be attacked and disfigured by old age and invalidity.”
>
> Text 37: King Yayāti said, “O learned, worshipable brāhmaṇa, I have
>   not yet satisfied my lusty desires with your daughter.” Śukrācārya
>   then replied, “You may exchange your old age with someone who will
>   agree to transfer his youth to you.”
>
> Text 38: When Yayāti received this benediction from Śukrācārya, he
>   requested his eldest son: My dear son Yadu, please give me your youth
>   in exchange for my old age and invalidity.
>
> Text 39: My dear son, I am not yet satisfied in my sexual desires. But
>   if you are kind to me, you can take the old age given by your maternal
>   grandfather, and I may take your youth so that I may enjoy life for a
>   few years more.
>
> Text 40: **Yadu replied**: **My dear father, you have already achieved old
>   age, although you also were a young man. But I do not welcome your old
>   age and invalidity, for unless one enjoys material happiness, one
>   cannot attain renunciation.**

Was Yadu right in denying his own father, Yayati's request?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [HInduism.SE]. Can you please add more description or background in your question for the readers who do not know what is Yadu's father's request and why Yadu declined it? Please read [ask] page. If we ask clearer question, the reception will be the same and there is a scope that your question reaches more audience. It will be helpful both for the readers and you too.

Comment: The problem with the question is "Was Yadu right..." The only possible answers to such a question are opinion-based. Perhaps there's a way in which the question can have a scriptural-based answer

Answer (score 2):

The crux of this story was mentioned in [Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01084.htm) of Mahabharata.

> Sukra then answered, 'I never speak an untruth. Even now, O king, art
>   thou attacked by decrepitude. But if thou likest, thou art competent
>   to transfer this thy decrepitude to another.'
>
> Yayati said, 'O Brahmana, let it be commanded by thee that that son of
>   mine who giveth me his youth shall enjoy my kingdom, and shall achieve
>   both virtue and fame.'
>
> Sukra replied, 'O son of Nahusha, thinking of me thou mayst transfer
>   this thy decrepitude to whomsoever thou likest. That son who shall
>   give thee his youth shall become thy successor to the throne. He shall
>   also have long life, wide fame, and numerous progeny!'"

---

After swapping his unexpected old age with Puru, he enjoyed all worldly desires for 1000 years.  After realising that the desires can't be put to an end by indulging in them, he [gives back youth to Puru.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01086.htm) And, he installed Puru as king after him.

The descendants of Yadu are the Yadavas and of Puru are the Pauravas.

---

So Sukra never said swapping of old age with his son, but with another person.  It was Yayati, out of anxiety proposed to swap old age with his son.

We have to remember that even after banishment Yadu became leader of Yadavas.  And, Pandu married Kunti from that family and Sri Krishna from Yadavas helped Pandavas.

What Yayati did was not correct and not according to Dharma.

That was why Yadu did prosper even after banishment . Further, the lineage of Puru was broken after the death of sons of Santanu.

---

So we have to understand that Dharma is subtle.

Respecting orders of one's father is correct but it depends on the situation.

Sri Rama went to the forest  as per Kaikeyi's wish,  conveyed to him as his father's order, and we venerate him.

Prahlada disobeyed his father's order and we venerate Prahlada.

---